# Auto optimisation for L cache for object's variables?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, cpu-cache

Frankly, this is a continue of [this my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227585/cdi-postconstruct-and-volatile-fields), inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53262717/1479414

Let's suppose we have a class:

```
public class Foo {
    private Integer x;

    public void setX(Integer x) {
       this.x = x;
    }

    public Integer getX() {
       return this.x;
    }
}
```

And let us consider **a very specific scenario**, when we have just two threads which interact with the `x` variable:

At time 1, a thread T1 is created

At time 2, T1 sets the value: `foo.setX(123);`

At time 3, a thread T2 is created

At time 4, T2 reads the value: `foo.getX();`

No other threads interact with this value. Both operations happen only once.

So there is no apparent `x` value read operations before the thread T2 does his job.

The question is: does any auto optimisation for L cache exist which can cache `null` value of the `x` variable, so the thread `T2` will read its cached value? 
In other words, do we need the `volatile` modifier in this particular scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a thread, it will see any value set before it is created.

In the Javadoc for java.util.concurrency for Java 11 under [Memory Visibility Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) and [JLS-17.4.5 for Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) states

> A call to start on a thread happens-before any action in the started thread.

NOTE: A thread only reads a cached value, when it re-reads a value in a cache line it has already in its cache. If it reads a cache line it has never read before or is no longer in a cache, it won't read a stale value.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! It sounds logical that when a new thread is created it should see the actualised value of any variable. However, could this statement be strengthened with some links to the specification?

Comment: @Andremoniy I have added a quote.

Answer (score 1):

T1 and T2 are executed sequentially and [cache is coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#WRITEPOLICIES), especially in this sequential use case.

So there is no way that T2 at time 4 will get a null value.

Comment: So you assume that the CPU cache has nothing to do with volatile-problem?

Comment: I do not assume that. I assume that because the execution of T1 and T2 is sequential, the cache will be coherent (no concurrency issue)

Comment: That was my question: some people claim that there exist an auto optimisaiton which acts independently of existent threads

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't know how to elaborate. It was said that there is a "auto optimisation for L* cache" which can cause the null value be cached and passed therefore to the thread T2. That was my question: does something similar really exist?